# Can't use s3 functions in Lambda (nodejs)

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS Lambda, I am pulling my hairs about calling S3 APIs in nodejs. I want to read the content of an S3 object, so here is my code:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

s3.getObject({
  Bucket: 'lambda-bucket',
  Key: 'test.html'
}, function (err, data) {
    console.log('this is happening!');
    console.log(data);
});

context.done();
}
```

I followed the API doc, but I don't even see the first log in CloudWatch. I also tried `putObject`, didn't seem to work as well. My runtime is nodejs4.3. Wish I could get some help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommending learning how asynchronous calls work in NodeJS before attempting to tackle AWS Lambda. In your code you are calling `context.done()` before your call to `s3.getObject()` is complete. This is causing the function to terminate before your S3 call finishes. Moving the `context.done()` call into the `getObject` callback will fix this:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 
  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  s3.getObject({
    Bucket: 'lambda-bucket',
    Key: 'test.html'
  }, function (err, data) {
    console.log('this is happening!');
    console.log(data);

    // Now that the S3 call is complete, 
    // we can terminate the Lambda function execution
    context.done();
  });    
}
```